# Converting comma-separated string of single-quoted numbers to int array

Tags: php, arrays, casting, type-conversion, iteration

I have a string:

```
'24','27','38'
```

I want to convert it:

```
(
    [0] => 24
    [1] => 27
    [2] => 38
)
```

The conversion: https://3v4l.org/oDPDl

```
array_map('intval', explode(',', $string))
```

gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
)
```

Basically, `array_map()` works when the numbers aren't quoted like `24,27,38', but I need a technique that works with quoted numbers.

One solution is looping over the array, but I don't want to do that. Can I achieve the above using only php functions (not [control structures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php) -- e.g. `foreach()`)?

Comment: Can you explain why you don't wan't to loop over the array?

Comment: Did you use `str_replace` before the array map?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan I think it would be costly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $arr = explode (",", str_replace("'", "", $str));
   foreach ($arr as $elem) 
      $array[] = trim($elem) ;
```

Comment: I don't want to loop over the array. :)

Comment: Is the loop necessary here? There shouldn't be any whitespace to trim.

Comment: In the example I saw spaces between numbers. If no spaces there, using loop is not necessary

Comment: @learner this answer does not return integer-typed values; it returns trimmed strings.  Why did you select this one?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following approach:

```
$str = "'24','27','38'";
$result = array_map(function($v){ return (int) trim($v, "'"); }, explode(",", $str));

var_dump($result);
```

The output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(24)
  [1]=>
  int(27)
  [2]=>
  int(38)
}
```

Comment: I don't want to loop over the array. :)

Comment: @learner, you will inevitably loop to cast each item to integer type

Answer (score 0):

Without looping:

```
$str= "'24','27','38'";
$arr = array_map("intval", explode(",", str_replace("'", "", $str)));
var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(24)
  [1]=>
  int(27)
  [2]=>
  int(38)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf()` can instantly return type-cast values if you ask it to.

Here is a technique that doesn't use an explicit loop: `sscanf(preg_replace())`

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RS4aF))

```
var_export(sscanf($string, preg_replace('/\d+/', '%d', $string)));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 24,
  1 => 27,
  2 => 38,
)
```

Or some developers might find this more professional/intuitive (other will disagree): ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DEN1q))

```
var_export(filter_var_array(explode("','", trim($string, "'")), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));
// same output as above
```

or perhaps this alternative which leverages more commonly used native functions:

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        function($v) {
            return (int)$v;
        },
        explode("','", trim($string, "'"))
    )
);
```

which simplifies to:

```
var_export(array_map('intval', explode("','", trim($string, "'"))));
// same output as above
```

---

For anyone who doesn't care about the datatype of the newly generated elements in the output array, here are a few working techniques that return string elements: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ctREb))

```
var_export(explode("','", trim($string, "'")));

var_export(preg_split('/\D+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));

var_export(preg_match_all('/\d+/', $string, $m) ? $m[0] : []);

var_export(filter_var_array(explode(',', $string), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
```